# multiple GPIO.add_event_detect doesn't show encoder output

Tags: gpio, python, gui

so i have 3 GPIO.add_event_detect's
each one comes with callback function
when only one GPIO.add_event_detect is enabled, it shows proper output
but if i add 3 of them it doesn't show anything while i turn encoders..

```
from Tkinter import *
from Tkinter import Listbox
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import threading
import random
import sys
import os

# detecting DISPLAY, setting DISPLAY 
if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
    print('no display found. Using :0.0')
    os.environ.__setitem__('DISPLAY', ':0.0')

rEncoder1_counter = 0
rEncoder2_counter = 0
rEncoder3_counter = 0

# GPIO Pins #
Enc_A = 17  
Enc_B = 27
#-----------#
Enc_C = 22  
Enc_D = 23
#-----------#
Enc_E = 24  
Enc_F = 25
#-----------#

# GPIO settings
GPIO.setwarnings(True)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#
GPIO.setup(Enc_A, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(Enc_B, GPIO.IN)
#
GPIO.setup(Enc_C, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(Enc_D, GPIO.IN)
#
GPIO.setup(Enc_E, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(Enc_F, GPIO.IN)

# reading encoder
def rEncoder1(Enc_A):
    global rEncoder1_counter
    sleep(0.002)
    Switch_A = GPIO.input(Enc_A)
    Switch_B = GPIO.input(Enc_B)
 
    if (Switch_A == 1) and (Switch_B == 0):
        rEncoder1_counter += 1
        print  (rEncoder1_counter)
        listbox.insert(END,rEncoder1_counter)
        while Switch_B == 0:
            Switch_B = GPIO.input(Enc_B)
        while Switch_B == 1:
            Switch_B = GPIO.input(Enc_B)
        return
 
    elif (Switch_A == 1) and (Switch_B == 1):
        rEncoder1_counter -= 1
        print  (rEncoder1_counter)
        listbox.insert(END,rEncoder1_counter) 
        while Switch_A == 1:
            Switch_A = GPIO.input(Enc_A)
        return
    else:
        return

def rEncoder2(Enc_C):
    global rEncoder2_counter
    sleep(0.002)
    Switch_C = GPIO.input(Enc_C)
    Switch_D = GPIO.input(Enc_D)
 
    if (Switch_C == 1) and (Switch_D == 0):
        rEncoder2_counter += 1
        print  (rEncoder2_counter)
        listbox.insert(END,rEncoder2_counter)
        while Switch_D == 0:
            Switch_D = GPIO.input(Enc_D)
        while Switch_D == 1:
            Switch_D = GPIO.input(Enc_D)
        return
 
    elif (Switch_C == 1) and (Switch_D == 1):
        rEncoder2_counter -= 1
        print  (rEncoder2_counter)
        listbox.insert(END,rEncoder2_counter) 
        while Switch_C == 1:
            Switch_C = GPIO.input(Enc_C)
        return
    else:
        return

def rEncoder3(Enc_E):
    global rEncoder3_counter
    sleep(0.002)
    Switch_E = GPIO.input(Enc_E)
    Switch_F = GPIO.input(Enc_F)
 
    if (Switch_E == 1) and (Switch_F == 0):
        rEncoder3_counter += 1
        print  (rEncoder3_counter)
        listbox.insert(END,rEncoder3_counter)
        while Switch_F == 0:
            Switch_F = GPIO.input(Enc_F)
        while Switch_F == 1:
            Switch_F = GPIO.input(Enc_F)
        return
 
    elif (Switch_E == 1) and (Switch_F == 1):
        rEncoder3_counter -= 1
        print  (rEncoder3_counter)
        listbox.insert(END,rEncoder3_counter) 
        while Switch_E == 1:
            Switch_E = GPIO.input(Enc_E)
        return
    else:
        return

# GPIO output detection
GPIO.add_event_detect(Enc_A, GPIO.RISING, callback=rEncoder1, bouncetime=10)
GPIO.add_event_detect(Enc_C, GPIO.RISING, callback=rEncoder2, bouncetime=10)
GPIO.add_event_detect(Enc_E, GPIO.RISING, callback=rEncoder3, bouncetime=10)

# window settings
window = Tk()
window.title("gui_test")

# window.geometry('800x600')
window.configure(bg='black')
window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

# font
#myFont = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=12, weight='bold')

# scrolbar
scrollbar = Scrollbar(window)

# listbox , font=myFont
listbox = Listbox(window, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
listbox.pack()
listbox.see("end")
#
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

# commanding mainloop for starting main loop
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a callback is running all other callbacks and the main program are blocked.

You have while loops in the callbacks which means they are blocked for periods of times.

I suggest you redesign and do the minimum amount of processing in each callback.  I suggest setting flags only, no while loops.

Comment: yeah i re done it, so now we are cool, all works without blocking.
thanks.

Comment: If you are happy with your new code it would be useful to add it to your question as a sort of before and after (to give others an idea of what to change).